# How do I define a oncomplete event on a CommandButton in PrimeFaces with a closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm extending a part of a PrimeFaces application with some JavaScript interactivity. It all starts with `CommandButton` which gets some data from the bean and calls then JavaScript. Currently, it looks something like this:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.doSomething}"
                                 oncomplete="doSomethingSimple()"
                                 value="Do something" />
```

Naturally, this is very simple function-based programming. There is no context, no closures, no OOP (if I needed some). I'd like to attach a normal JavaScript event to the `CommandButton`, e.g. like this with jQuery:

```
$('.myCommandButton').on('complete', function () {
     ...
})
```

However, `complete` is not a DOM event and basically, only PrimeFaces knows when it's to be called. Is there still a way to replace attribute-based scripting with a "normal" JavaScript event handling?

Comment: If you will find a way to pass source element id (or something) you could use the `<p:ajaxStatus` http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatusScript.jsf;jsessionid=1entnayzbetp16my2wok6pmgq , just like the way JSF `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` can be used

Answer (score 7):

PrimeFaces uses under the covers jQuery to deal with ajax requests. So, could just hook on the generic [`$.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) handler. The source is available as property of 3rd argument `options`:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options) {
    var $source = $("[id='" + options.source + "']");

    if ($source.hasClass("myCommandButton")) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Or, if you're using PrimeFaces 4.0 or newer, hook on PrimeFaces-specific `pfAjaxComplete` event:

```
$(document).on("pfAjaxComplete", function(event, xhr, options) {
    var $source = $("[id='" + options.source + "']");

    if ($source.hasClass("myCommandButton")) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Or, if you're mixing PrimeFaces with "plain" HTML/jQuery and would like to apply on both:

```
$(document).on("ajaxComplete pfAjaxComplete", function(event, xhr, options) {
    var $source = $("[id='" + options.source + "']");

    if ($source.hasClass("myCommandButton")) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Regardless of the way, the `$source` represents thus the jQuery object of the original HTML DOM element on which the ajax action was been triggered, which is in case of this particular example the `<p:commandButton>` itself. This offers you the possibility to delegate it further to the desired handler by e.g. examining element's class.

Answer (score 0):

With PrimeFaces 4.0, `ajaxComplete` was replaced with `pfAjaxComplete`. See [Issue 5933](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5933) for more details.

That being said, I was able to get it to work as follows:

```
$(document).on('pfAjaxComplete', function() {
    foo.bar()
});
```