# implement a general ajax method

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to implement a general ajax method that will execute for every link in my page?

I mean to execute a js function like checkCarousel() but without the need to define it on an "oncomplete" ajax attribute for every single link on my project

```
<p:commandLink action="#{someBean.active}" 
      update="@all" oncomplete="checkCarousel();" >
      <img width="70" src="resources/images/logo.png"                          
         alt="LOGO" style="border: none;"/>
 </p:commandLink>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what a simple Google search got me:

> PrimeFaces uses under the covers jQuery to deal with ajax requests. So, your best bet is to hook on the generic $.ajaxComplete() handler.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, options) {
    var $source = $("[id='" + options.source + "']");

    if ($source.hasClass("myCommandButton")) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

> The $source represents the jQuery object of the original HTML DOM
>   element on which the ajax action was been triggered, which is in case
>   of this particular example the  itself. This offers
>   you the possibility to delegate it further to the desired handler by
>   e.g. examining element's class.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937407/how-do-i-define-a-oncomplete-event-on-a-commandbutton-in-primefaces-with-a-closu)

Comment: Thank you! tryed out but didn't work, and did some research... this was the way to do it in previous versions of PF, I believe that with PF 4.0 on wards this is deprecated. Posted correct answer below

Answer (score 0):

With Primefaces 4.0 onwards the jquery .ajaxComplete function is replaced with an own Pf method. Here's code;

```
$(document).on('pfAjaxComplete', function(e, xhr, settings) {
        alert("An ajax request has been completed!");
        //other stuff
});
```